# Hazelcast - DurableExecutorService behaviour whilst repartitioning

Tags: partitioning, hazelcast

I'm looking for clarity on the behaviour of the DurableExecutorService during the repartitioning of a cluster.

Imagine we have submitted a runnable to be executed on the key owner of key1.
Whilst this is executing, an event occurs causing the cluster to repartition. Does the repartition event wait for the running executor task to complete?  Or does Hz terminate the task before restarting it on the new key owner?  Or does Hz just continue with the repartition event and any access to caches made by the executor that were assumed to be on the local member, may result in the data being pulled from the new key owner. What about tasks in the executor's work queue?  Will these continue to be processed even though this member is no longer the key owner?  or will they be moved from this executorService instance and run on a new instance within the owning member ?
Sooo many questions.  Hazelcast docs are frustratingly sparse on this service.